# Tweening numbers in D3 v4 not working anymore like in v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out why my tweening numbers (counting up or down) code in Version 4 of D3 doesn't function any more.

Here is my code:

```
var pieText = svg4.append("text")
    .attr("class", "pieLabel")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text(0)
    .attr("dy", "0.2em")
    .style("font-size", 19)
    .style("fill", "#46596b")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

d3.selectAll(".pieLabel").transition()
  .delay(500)
  .duration(1000)
  .tween("text", function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, d.value);
    return function(t) {
      this.textContent = form(i(t));
    };
  });
```

The console.log tells me that the interpolation works fine. 
So what has changed? And how do I get it to work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the interpolation works fine, what exactly *"doesn't function any more"*?

Comment: Console.log(this.textContent) inside the return function counts up/down but I don't see any actual effect on the svg text elements

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not in the code you posted. The function `form()` might be the culprit. We will never know, however, unless you provide all relevant parts of the code or—even better—a [mcve].

Comment: OK here a JSbin: https://jsbin.com/faxehejoyo/1/edit?html,output
It works with version 3.5 but not with 4.

Comment: @altocumulus OP is correct, that code won't work in v4 because of `this` in the inner function.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Correct, and I have to admit that you, again, beat me to it! However, I posted my own answer as it provides a little more background. I don't think that this *feature* is covered by that section of the changelog you quoted.

Comment: @altocumulus indeed. The fact that the third argument was changed doesn't necessarily leads to this (no pun intended) behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is just `this` inside the inner function, which will no longer work as it worked in v3.

Let's prove it. Have a look at the console here, using D3 v3, `this` is the DOM element:

```js
d3.select("p").transition()
  .tween("foo", function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, 1);
    return function(t) {
      console.log(this)
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Now the same snippet, using D3 v4... `this` is now the `window` object:

```js
d3.select("p").transition()
  .tween("foo", function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, 1);
    return function(t) {
      console.log(this)
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

**Solution**: keep the reference to `this` in the outer function as a variable (traditionally named `self`, but here I'll name it `node`):

```
d3.selectAll(".pieLabel").transition()
    .delay(500)
    .duration(1000)
    .tween("text", function(d) {
        var node = this;
        //keep a reference to 'this'
        var i = d3.interpolate(node.textContent, d.value);
        return function(t) {
            node.textContent = form(i(t));
            //use that reference in the inner function
        };
    });
```

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
var widthpie = 250,
  heightpie = 300,
  radius = Math.min(widthpie, heightpie) / 2;

var data = [{
  antwort: "A",
  value: 0.5
}, {
  antwort: "B",
  value: 0.4
}];

var form = d3.format(",%");

var body4 = d3.select("#chart1");

var svg4 = body4.selectAll("svg.Pie")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", widthpie)
  .attr("height", heightpie)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + widthpie / 2 + "," + heightpie / 2 + ")");

var pieText = svg4.append("text")
  .attr("class", "pieLabel")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .text(0)
  .attr("dy", "0.2em")
  .style("font-size", 19)
  .style("fill", "#46596b")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

d3.selectAll(".pieLabel").transition()
  .delay(500)
  .duration(1000)
  .tween("text", function(d) {
    var node = this;
    var i = d3.interpolate(node.textContent, d.value);
    return function(t) {
      node.textContent = form(i(t));
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

PS: I'm using Firebug in the snippets because S.O. snippet don't log the window object correctly.

Comment: This should be the best answer, given that it is the diff between v4 & v5.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by a change which is not documented in the changelog. D3 v3 [calls](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/transition/transition.js#L132) the inner function returned by the callback passed to `transition.tween()` on every tick passing the current node as the `this` context:

```
tweens[--n].call(node, e);
```

As of v4, however, this is no longer the case when the inner function is [called](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/transition/schedule.js#L138):

```
tween[i].call(null, t);
```

Passing `null` to that function will be replaced with the global object. In this case `this` in your function no longer points to current element as was true for v3. The remedy was already been laid out by Gerardo in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834918/4235784) and is even suggested by the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_tween) on v4:

```
transition.tween("attr.fill", function() {
  var node = this, i = d3.interpolateRgb(node.getAttribute("fill"), "blue");
  return function(t) {
    node.setAttribute("fill", i(t));
  };
});
```

Hence, you need a closure to keep a reference to the current element as it is referenced as `this` in the callback provided to `transition.tween()`.

Answer (score -2):

i thing i copy this code i dont know where, if any one knew just give referance. i use this to add transition to path, i hope this give you an idea

**Use this to append the transition**

```
.transition()
              .duration(2000)
              .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
```

**this the function**

```
function tweenDash() {
    return function(t) {
        var l = path.node().getTotalLength();
        interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);

        //t is fraction of time 0-1 since transition began

        var p = path.node().getPointAtLength(t * l);

        return interpolate(t);
    }
}
```